# Enabling internet connectivity through software

Tags: active-directory, internet

I want to make my network Active Directory controlled.

I want to enable internet connectivity in my client computers through some kind of startup/logon script.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy Server that requires AD authentication and have Active Directory set the proxy settings of user.

You also should have the users on a LAN that has no route to the internet when doing this.

Comment: Is there any other way without using a normal proxy?

Comment: Without a proxy you'd have to use some sort of 802.1x on the network to stop people from sending traffic to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to restrict internet access, you could set up a group policy in AD that points internet explorer to a non-existent proxy.  [Here's a link with some instructions for setting proxy on GPO.](http://www.stbernard.com/ip4kb/iPrism/Networking/Sessions-Clients/Browsers/IP0346.htm)  If you're trying to enable only to some sites, you could put these in the ignore list for the proxy server using the same GPO -- requests for these sites would then go to the gateway.

The drawback is that this works only if IE is the browser, if a user installs Firefox -- or any other browser or network application -- they can set/remove the proxy themselves.

Filtering is usually best done at a gateway or proxy (in one place).  Is there a specific objection to a proxy?  There are [some](http://www.advproxy.net/) [good](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and easy to install/configure free ones out there.

Comment: And if you can shell out for it, ISA is slick and definitely the best-integrated proxy for an AD environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy cheap routers with linux installations that you can customize.

One option, therefore, is to configure the router to gateway clients that have signed in correctly, and drop everyone else's packets.

-Adam

Comment: I'm infact having Winroute firewall and this doesn't seem possible with it